# When trying to unistall apache2 there is a problem it happen

Tags: pi-4, apache-httpd

When trying to unistall apache2  there is a problem it happen.
I try to unistall the apache2 files from raspberry pi 4 but when i try this command

$ sudo apt-get purge apache2

after it finished it says:

dpkg: warning: while removing apache2, directory '/var/www/html' not empty so not removed

does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Don't ever use apt-get use apt

Comment: That comment means that you've added some of your own (not package maintained) files into /var/www/html and apt or apt-get (doesn't matter) can't remove them. 
It's not specific to the RPi.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the directory and contents manually if they are not needed.

The purge process does not know if it is safe to delete the directory and contents or not.